# Why Dart holds *double standard* between `==` and `>=`

Tags: dart

I have two `int` values in Dart, test them equals or not with `==` previously, it was fine. Now I have to test if first one is greater or equals to the second one, so I changed `==` to `>=` instinctively, but it seems Dart was not happy with me doing that

1. I double checked documentation of Dart, `>=` should work to test `greater or equals` operation
2. IMO, in the end, if `>=` has something wrong, then the same should come to `==`

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is you are trying to call the `int.>=` operator with a nullable value which is not allowed since it expects a type compatible with `num`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/num/operator_greater_equal.html

Comment: because `_values` seemingly can be null. And if it's null, then `_values.length` will also be null. You can perfectly check if `something == null`. But you cannot check if `something >= null` Because how would you determine if `3 > null`. That's just not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing two different operators which comes from different part of the Dart language. The `==` operator is defined on `Object`:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html

Which needs to be able to compare every type of object including `null`. The reason why the `==` operator does not have `Object?` as input parameter is because of the following detail in the Dart Language Specification (page 167) under the section "Equality":

> Evaluation of an equality expression ee of the form e1 == e2 proceeds as follows:
>
> - The expression `e1` is evaluated to an object `o1`.
> - The expression `e2` is evaluated to an object `o2`.
> - If either `o1` or `o2` is the null object (17.4), then `ee` evaluates to `true` if both `o1` and `o2` are the null object and to `false` otherwise. Otherwise,
> - evaluation of ee is equivalent to the method invocation `o1.==(o2)`
>
> ...

https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf

So based on third rule, the language itself will make sure that `null` values are compared correctly and therefore the `Object.==` method will never see a `null` object as its input.

---

The other operator is `>=` and comes (in your case) from `num` which `int` extends from:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/num/operator_greater_equal.html

And is specified to accept only `num` (so `int` or `double`) which are a non-nullable type (`null` is therefore not allowed).

You are then trying to call the `num.>=` operator with the result from `values?.length`. This is a problem since `values` is nullable and can therefore potentially be `null`. And when you use the `?.` operator, you are saying that if `values` are `null`, don't care calling `.lenght` but instead just return `null`.

So the type of `values?.length` ends up being `int?` which is not compatible with `num`.

Comment: I'm sure indeed it's a basic&simple concept for real Dart developers, but not so obvious for those has no such background. thank you.

Comment: @http8086 I fully understand how this confusion can happen. Should be noted that this is not really Dart specific since other languages also have different valid input values when comparing `==` and `>=`. I think the confusion here mostly come from the fact that nullable types is a thing in Dart and `num.>=` does not accept these. But I am not one of those who have downvoted you even if your title could be less "judgmental" (best word I could find). :)

Comment: oh, I realized it, I'm not native speaker, for me, it is just literally meaning double, but I think it has rich things out of it for native speakers especially w/ daily context